# iOS app not working on iPhone 6 Plus simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-simulator

My app works just fine with the simulators of all iPhones from 4S to 6, but does not work properly on iPhone 6 Plus.

I am using a tableview to display my data and on the right side of each cell is a "+" button. It works fine for all other simulators, it does what it should, but on iPhone 6 Plus if you tap a cell or tap "+", nothing happens. Also, if I go into edit-mode of the tableview, I can't even hit the "-" on the left side.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Could be an issue with constraints "adding a transparent view" above your buttons. Try to use the "3D" feature view of XCode 6.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am not using any constraints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what it was,
thank you @Larme, it had to do with a "transparent view". 
i have a refreshcontrol added wich was layed over the tableview... but only on iphone 6 plus...

[self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:self.refreshControl];

did it for me ;)